# FileUpload - if file name exist concat a number between parentheses at the end of name

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to upload file (one at a time) to a folder:

`GetUniqueName` function (mentioned below) will return a unique file name

### This is the code I use to do it:

```
public static string GetUniqueName(string fileName)
{
        string dir = Globals.Directories.GetCustomCategoryThumbnailDir();
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        string fileNameWE = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*" + fileExtension)
                                .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                .ToArray();
        string uniqueName = fileNameWE;
        int nextNum = 0;
        bool fileExist = false;
        string pattern = @"(.*)\(([\d]+)\)";

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var tempFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            var match = Regex.Match(tempFileName, pattern);

            if (tempFileName.Equals(fileNameWE))
            {
                // file exist in folder
                fileExist = true;
            }
            if (tempFileName.StartsWith(fileNameWE) && match.Success)
            {
                // there is a file name that start with "fileToUpload" name, we want to to take the number
                nextNum = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
                nextNum++;
            }
        }

        if (nextNum == 0 && !fileExist)
        {
            // filename dont exist                
            return fileNameWE + fileExtension;
        }
        if (nextNum == 0 && fileExist) 
        {
            // the file name exist without (1)
            fileNameWE = $"{fileNameWE}(1)";
            return fileNameWE + fileExtension;
        }
        else
        {
            var haveParentheses = Regex.Match(fileNameWE, pattern);

            if (haveParentheses.Success)
            {
                // we need to reset the nextNum
                nextNum = 1; 
            }

            // return the new unique name with suffix
            fileNameWE = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameWE, nextNum);
            return fileNameWE + fileExtension;
        }
}
```

- All the solution that i find online are keeping the file name unique with the use of `GUID` or `DateTime`
- for other cases that i checked the function work correctly and will return a "good" file name.

### Some examples:

- The folder contain:

  - army.png

I want to upload: `army.png`

- The folder will contain:

  - army.png
  - army(1).png

I want to upload again: `army.png`

- The folder will contain:

  - army.png
  - army(1).png
  - army(2).png

I want to upload : `army(2).png`

- The folder will contain:

  - army.png
  - army(1).png
  - army(2).png
  - army(2)(1).png

I want to upload again: `army(2).png`

- The folder will contain:

  - army.png
  - army(1).png
  - army(2).png
  - army(2)(1).png
  - army(2)(2).png

I want to upload again: `army(2).png`

- The folder will contain:

  - army.png
  - army(1).png
  - army(2).png
  - army(2)(1).png
  - army(2)(2).png
  - army(2)(3).png

I want to upload : `army(2)(2).png`

- The folder will contain:

  - army.png
  - army(1).png
  - army(2).png
  - army(2)(1).png
  - army(2)(2).png
  - army(2)(3).png
  - army(2)(2)(1).png

How can I fix the function so it will return the correct string?

Comment: should the correct return to "army(2).png" be "army(2)(2).png". Because if you only add a (1) to the end, the logic is "has a file with the same name?, if no, add (1) and recursive call".

Comment: Yes. my bad- the file name should be `army(2)(2).png` and not `army(2)(1)(1).png` i will correct the question

Comment: I've updated my answer again. I would usually not bother but since the code in the accepted answer is so much more complicated then mine I thought I better show you a simpler way.

Comment: I didn't checked it because its don't "cut&paste" take a look at my post, for instance the function gets only the file name (include his ex), and not to full path.

Comment: I've changed it to get only the file name..

Comment: Thanks. now the `fileName` parameter name inside the while - need to be changed also + the function should only return the new unique file name

Comment: just checked it and it dont work for the case that there is a file name in the folder `army(1)(2).png` and also `army(1)(1).png` > I tried to upload a file named `army.png` I expected it to return a new name `army(1)(3)` but it didn't

Comment: You can simply return the `fileName` instead of the `targetPath`. As for your second comment, that wasn't in the test scenarios you provided  but I'll check.

Comment: Actually, your original scenarios seems to suggest it should return `army(2).png` which it does....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, unfortunately I couldn't found the problem in your poster algorithm, but I wrote a new one, and I tested with several names. Appears to be working out. Please check-it:

```
public static string GetUniqueName(string fileName)
{
    var dir = Globals.Directories.GetCustomCategoryThumbnailDir();

    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    var fileNameWE = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*" + fileExtension)
        .Select(Path.GetFileName)
        .Where(w => w.StartsWith(fileNameWE)) // included condition.
        .ToArray();

    if (!files.Any()) return fileName;

    var pattern = fileNameWE
        .Select(s => "[" + s + "]")
        .Aggregate("", (ac, i) => ac + i);

    var regex = new Regex(pattern + @"[(](?<counter>\d)[)]");

    var previous = files
        .Select(file => regex.Match(file))
        .Where(match => match.Success)
        .OrderByDescending(match => int.Parse(match.Groups["counter"].Value))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    var correctIndex = previous != null
        ? int.Parse(previous.Groups["counter"].Value) + 1
        : 1;

    return fileNameWE + "(" + correctIndex + ")" + fileExtension;
}
```

**TEST Scenarios:**

`army(2).png    ->  army(2)(2).png`
`army.png       ->  army(3).png`
`army(1).png    ->  army(1)(1).png`

Answer (score 3):

### Final version

This is tested and working according to all the cases on the question:

```
public static string GetUniqueName(string fileName)
{
    string dir = @"C:\Users\support\Desktop\Zohar\SO\Upload\Target";
    var targetPath = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(targetPath);
    string fileNameWE = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(targetPath);
    int i = 1;
    while (File.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        fileName = string.Format("{0}({1}){2}", fileNameWE, i, fileExtension);
        targetPath = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
        i++;
    }
    return targetPath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. but i prefer not to use recursive method

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use recursive methods?

Comment: The boss want to avoid them :)

Comment: also, take a look at the files in that folder  the number is not always (1)- it should be increased every time it exist

Comment: " I except the function to return army(2)(1)(1).png" that's what my function will return...

Comment: Also, I've edited my answer to include a non-recursive version.

Comment: Thanks Zohar! I updated my question with examples. please take a look

Comment: Check out the third version in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should just run a loop, right?

```
var fileName = fileNameWE + fileExtension;

while(File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, fileName)))
{
  fileNameWE += "(1)";
  fileName = fileNameWE + fileExtension;
} 

return fileName;
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question with examples, please take a look